# Performing AES Encryption is Ruby compared to Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am struggling at this one part of code where I need to decrypt AES on my server side (Ruby) from a client. I know all the information, but I am struggling with re-producing the encryption.

I am currently using `CryptoJS` from https://github.com/brix/crypto-js. I am not sure which version of AES it is using which might be my first problem.

An example of how I currently encrypt my data in Javascript is:

```
encodeURIComponent(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message","Key").toString())
```

Right now I am currently using `openssl` and `cgi` in Ruby to try to decrypt. This is wrong and not working, but I wanted to show what I am trying as I believe it is close. I don't understand how the key is used in the encryption, but I am following the example I found [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#class-OpenSSL::Cipher-label-Encrypting+and+decrypting+some+data)

```
require "openssl"
require "cgi"

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-128-CBC')
cipher.encrypt
key = "Key"
iv = cipher.random_iv

encrypted = cipher.update("Message") + cipher.final

puts CGI::escape(encrypted.to_s)
```

I have just put `"Message"` and `"Key"` to not share my information, I am an amateur when it comes to security and cryptography, but I have done these things in lower level languages without problems. I believe the problem happens in two main areas

1. My lack of knowledge of how these high level languages work, and the libraries I am using
2. The strings are sometimes UTF-8 vs UTF-16 in these langauges, so passing the `"Message"` as a string might be causing problems

FULL EXAMPLE OF ENCRYPTION AND DECRYPTION IN JAVASCRIPT:

Encrypting and URL encoding with input 1:

```
encodeURIComponent(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("1","Key").toString())
```

Result:

```
"U2FsdGVkX19Lp8ItQaO5h6Lj68sheHeYrIkJAfqt1Tw%3D"
```

Decoding URL and Decryption:

```
CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(decodeURIComponent("U2FsdGVkX19Lp8ItQaO5h6Lj68sheHeYrIkJAfqt1Tw%3D"), "Key").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
```

Result:

```
"1"
```

Comment: You could at least post code that can run with a test key and message, right? Where is your URL encoding / decoding? We're not here to do your job.

Comment: Your `"Key"` in CryptoJS is not an actual key. It's a password which is used to derive a key. As far as I understand the OpenSSL wrapper in Ruby, this is not the case. The two code snippets are completely different. The answer would be easy if the CryptoJS code would be changeable (is it?). Why do you want to symmetric encryption in the browser. It doesn't provide any more security than HTTPS would.

Comment: If you're using only symmetric encryption you need the exact same key at the server and the client. If you send the encryption key from the server to the client or the other way around you need to encrypt your symmetric encryption key. The easiest way to do this would be to use TLS. If you use TLS, then the data as well as key are encrypted, so you don't need to encrypt it yourself. This doesn't provide any security, just a little bit of obfuscation. You should read: https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

Comment: Have you thought about using a library like [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor) which has a secure implementation for Ruby, JavaScript and a couple other languages?

Comment: I am using it as a simple barrier. The message isn't that important. I just wanted to create unique urls using this with data point inside that are not easily visible. I could just use encoding but like the fact that there is a password even thought it is not secure to separate certain client code access by department and page.

Answer (score 1):

At least one of your problems is noted by Artjom B noted in the comment above, and this is a frequent problem with trying to get crypto-js to interoperate with other libraries: crypto-js is not taking in a "Key" the way you are using it but instead a password.  Passwords are not keys!!!

Internally, crypto-js uses a very poor algorithm for converting the password into a key.  The algorithm is poor for two reasons: (1) it is based upon the insecure MD5, and (2) converting passwords to keys should be a slow process to deter brute force guessing of passwords.  In crypto-js, the process is not slow.

To get you headed the right direction, do not call:

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message","Password")
```

Instead, call

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", key, { iv: iv });
```

You might also need to explore padding to get it to interoperate with Ruby.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out! Should this be similar to the Ruby code I'm running or are there mistakes there as well.

Comment: @napkinsterror I am not a ruby expert, but the only potential issue I see with the ruby is that AES keys are by definition one of 16, 24, or 32 bytes.  I don't know what ruby does under the hood when you pass it something smaller: maybe it pads it out with 0s.  One thing to remember is that the same IV that was used for encryption should also be used for decryption.  The IV is not secret and is typically put at the beginning of the cipher text so that the receiving end can read it at the beginning for decryption.